# Alternative to ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock?

Tags: asp.net

The ASP.NET function **ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock** can be used to register a chunk of JavaScript code that will be added to the page when it's rendered.  The idea here is that you could have multiple instances of various user controls trying to register the same script over and over, but this ensures that it will only be included once.

The problem is, you don't really have any control over **where** the code is added to the page. This will insert the code inside the **BODY** tag of your page, but I need to add something (not limited to JavaScript code) into the **HEAD** block.

I'm well aware of various methods of adding something to the HEAD block via a **ContentPlaceHolder** block or by **"Head.Controls.Add** but these options do not address the problem of the same thing being added multiple times.

Is there an existing way to do this, or do I have to write a class that does something similar to **ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock** except targeting the HEAD block?

Comment: Why do you *need* something in the head?

Comment: There are many things that go only in the head, like meta tags, stylesheet links, etc.

Comment: Your list of things conspicuously didn't include scripts.

Comment: For good reason. First, I am not worried about JavaScript. Second, why make a specific solution that covers JavaScript and fails to cover the more general situation that works with other things as well.  (I've edited my original post to be more clear that this idea is not just for JavaScript.)

Answer (score 0):

I threw together a user control. There's nothing in the markup at all, so you can just add a new Web Forms User Control to your project and put this in the code behind:

```
public partial class ScriptControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    private Dictionary<string, string> _scripts = new Dictionary<string, string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

    public void RegisterScript(string key, string script)
    {
        if(!_scripts.ContainsKey(key)) _scripts.Add(key, script);
    }

    protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        writer.WriteFullBeginTag("script");
        foreach(var script in _scripts.Values) writer.Write(script);
        writer.WriteEndTag("script");
    }
}
```

Just add the directive to your page markup:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="uc" TagName="ScriptControl" 
    Src="ScriptControl.ascx" %>
```

(where "ScriptControl.ascx" is whatever you've named the control)
and then you can add it wherever you need to, including in the header.

```
<head runat="server">
    <uc:ScriptControl id="HeaderScriptControl" runat="server"/>
</head>
```

The usage is pretty much the same:

```
HeaderScriptControl.RegisterScript("myScript",
    @"alert(""hello, world!"")");
```

Comment: Yeah, thanks, but I'd already done something more or less like that.  I was trying to make sure there wasn't some native solution I was overlooking.  Also, this wouldn't work because it assumes you're doing JavaScript.